# IndexError: index 1000 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1000

Tags: python, for-loop, numpy, indexing

I am very new to python and indexing is still difficult for me. I am trying to plot few values using iterative operation but it seems it is not working and giving me above error. Please help me. Thanks.

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as mp

e = np.exp
z = np.arange(1000)


for i in z:
    while True:
    H_2 = 0.58*e(-(z[i]/81)**2)
    i += 1

mp.scatter(H_2 , z, c = 'r')
mp.show()
```

Comment: Indexes are zero-based.

Comment: What do you think `while True:` does?

Comment: I thought it is a loop so it will come back again to check if it satisfies the condition ' if i is within range of z'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is giving you the error `i += 1`

If you plan on using the `while` loop, don't forget to add your `break` statement, otherwise you'll be stuck in an infinite loop. Without any additional details, I don't see why it is necessary in this case.

In addition to that, I would define `H_2` as an empty list, and append any values in your calculation to it. According to the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter), `H_2` needs to be an array-like value.

So it should look like:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as mp

e = np.exp
z = np.arange(1000)
H_2 = []

for i in z:
    H_2.append(0.58*e(-(i/81)**2))

mp.scatter(H_2 , z, c = 'r')
mp.show()
```

Hopefully the graph appears as expected.

Comment: `z[i]` in the body of the for loop should probably just be `i`

Comment: alternatively, `H_2 = [0.58*e(-(i/81)**2) for i in z]`

Comment: You're right about `z[i]` just being `i` thanks for pointing that out. I also think using list comprehension would be a better approach as you mentioned, but the OP is new to python so I just left it as is. @Hamms

Comment: I don't think any use of a loop is appropriate here. `H_2 = 0.58*e(-(z/81)**2)` is the proper way to use numpy arrays.

Comment: Thanks @freshhmints, thanks a lot for the useful answer. It has worked perfectly. Sorry for late reply.

Answer (score 1):

So just as a general primer to indexes you need to remember that indexes are zero based.  So if you have an array of 5 elements the index 0 will get you the first element, etc and index 4 will get you the 5th and last element.  That being said index 5 is therefore trying to access the 6th element and so is invalid.

Now to Python, you should know that the 'for x in list' statement will iterate through all the elements in the lost, placing the actually value and not the index into the variable x.

Comment: Thanks @karina for useful comment.